# SharePoint 2010 - Allow Users to Add Pages to Wiki but not Edit Web Parts of Current Page

Tags: 2010, permissions, wiki, web-part-page

I'm new to SharePoint administration, currently working with 2010. I'm trying to give all users read and create page permissions on a wiki site, so that people can add pages to our internal wiki. But I don't want them to be able to edit the layout on the pages. I would like them to use the built in rich content editor to add content.

I've traced the permission down to the level of having the Edit Items permission under List Permissions. But my problem is that the Edit Items permission seems to allow them to edit the web parts of the page. Is there a way to grant new page permissions without granting web page layout editing permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in the list of permissions the permission in charge (for SHARED Views) is called which enables all these actions: "Add and Customize Pages"  -  Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible editor.

You could restrict to ADD-ing list Items only, using a Permission Level (enable the "Add Items" in  the List permissions sections and remove EDIT, etc.)

However, to my knowledge you could hide the button (Add Web Part) in the Insert tab of the Ribbon as the simplest, via a Custom Action.

C:\Marius

Comment: I actually didn't realize that by editing a wiki page without clicking the "edit this page" link it still records the version history. I think I should be okay with the way it works right now.  I also figured out that I can deny site creation by turning off the Site Creation Self Service permission on the web app [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yardman/archive/2011/08/22/configuring-sharepoint-2010-self-service-site-creation.aspx)

Comment: I've updated my answer  -if you are actually interested in allowing people to CREATE but not EDIT list Items (Wiki pages included) you could use the Permission Level and assign it to either Users/Groups (recomanded Groups and add Individual to these groups afterwards).